# On the iPhone, can I let YouTube run in the background and play the audio while I use other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

For example, if there is some live stream, or some videos that I can just listen to, and then I'd like to use other apps such as Gmail or Facebook, can I go to those apps without YouTube interrupting the video?

Currently YouTube stops playing the video when I go to another app.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to signup for YouTube Premium to have this feature. You can signup here:

https://www.youtube.com/premium

The price is currently 11.99$ per month.

A free method of achieving something similar is to use a non-Safari browser such as Opera Mini, and open youtube.com in that browser. Start the video, exit the browser and the audio stops. Then swipe up from the bottom to access the Control Center, you'll see playback controls in there for the YouTube contents. Press play to keep the audio playing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. First of all download Firefox browser for iOS. Then navigate to youtube.com and play some video. Hit the browser's menu button (sitting in top left corner as of Aug 19), then hit 'Request desktop site'. When the browser will reload the page play the video again, then activate notification center (not the control center) by swiping from the top edge of the screen (works for pre X iPhones, I don't know how to activate notification center on X and later). You will see rewind and pause controls. Lock the phone. The video will stop playing. Now press the lock or the home button. The controls will pop again. Now you press Play button and that's it. The video is playing in background from now, you can unlock the phone and switch to other apps freely.

Answer (score -1):

You can still try different browsers to get this done.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=trC48_SZYss

Comment: An answer must be more than a link. The answer should be understandable without the link.